# How to reformat JSON in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying out d3.js from a rails app to give me pretty graphs. One of the graphs I am trying out is a [forced directed graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). In order to create this the JSON needs to be in the format

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel"},
    {"name":"Napoleon"},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine"},
    {"name":"Mme.Magloire"}
 ],
"links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},
    {"source":3,"target":2,"value":6}
]
}
```

I currently have produced JSON from my database using this query:

```
 User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.user_id").select(" users.name, relationships.source, relationships.target,relationships.value")
```

which was created in the controller as follows

```
 def index
       render :json =>  User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.user_id").select(" users.name, relationships.source, relationships.target,relationships.value")
  end
end
```

and the result looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Myriel","source":121,"target":1,"value":1},{"name":"Napoleon","source":119,"target":2,"value":2},    {"name":"Myriel","source":121,"target":1,"value":2},{"name":"Myriel","source":121,"target":3,"value":1},{"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","source":122,"target":2,"value":3}]
```

Is there a simple way to map my JSON to what I need?

Comment: Could you post the code you wrote to create that JSON from the query?

Comment: you can try this `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your-result)`

Comment: you can use prettyjsonresponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in another answer, create a class method:

```
class User
  def self.including_relationships
    User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.user_id").select("users.name, relationships.user_id, relationships.target,relationships.value").each_with_object(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}) do |a, obj| 
      obj['nodes'] << a.slice('name')
      obj['links'] << a.slice('source', 'target', 'value')
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
def index
  render :json =>  User.including_relationships
end
```

I named method as `including_relationships` since it is not really creating a JSON instead converting the data into a `Hash` object, you can name it as you wish.

Comment: OK. Thanks this worked. Although only when I understood the slice function which chops the array according to its parameter. In other words I was getting errors until I matched a.slice(' to the User.joins statement. Therefore I changed obj['links'] << a.slice('source', 'target', 'value') to obj['links'] << a.slice('user_id', 'followsid', 'value')

Answer (score 2):

You can write a class method for User model and that method will return the json as you need.

```
def get_json
  json_data = User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.user_id").select(" users.name, relationships.user_id, relationships.target,relationships.value")

  {
    'nodes' => json_data.collect {|json| json.slice('name')},
    'links' => json_data.collect {|json| json.slice('source', 'target', 'value')}
  }
end
```

Comment: I get the error NoMethodError in UserController#index
undefined method `source' for #<User id: 121, name: "Maymie Borer">      (this is the first name in the User database).       It highlights the line 'links' => json_data.collect {|json| json.slice('source', 'target', 'value')}